# How to show both .TS and .JS files in Visula Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2017, web-essentials

I want to show .js file when I'm working with .ts as for the image,

[image: click here to show the image]

Added "Web Essentials 2017" from marketplace, still I can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the project and then Show All Files button?